# Running a py file as a script Django

Tags: django, scheduled-tasks, pythonanywhere

I have created a Django app which I have uploaded to PythonAnywhere.

I want to use the below code to run as a separate task, which basically runs through all of the bookings in the system and sends an email if the booking has passed today's date.

I previously had this in the Views.py file and the code works fine when the page refreshes but I basically want it to be run separate each morning at a particular time.

The issue I am having if I try to run the py file even locallly "py completed_bookings.py" it does not recognise any of the imports. Examples include **"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sendgrid'"** and **"ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package"**

I think this may be down to the structure or the way I am trying to run it but unsure how this is suppose to be done. Currently this file is sitting with the rest of my app files.

[image]

Thanks in advance for any help.

Below is the py file I created in the app to be run separate.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import datetime
from sendgrid import SendGridAPIClient
from sendgrid.helpers.mail import Mail
from twilio.rest import Client
import os 
from .models import ASPBookings, Athlete, BFBWBookings, SchoolTourBookings



def completed_bookings(request):

    date_today = datetime.datetime.now().date()

    asp_date_data = ASPBookings.objects.all()

    for booking in asp_date_data:
        if booking.booking_date < date_today:
            if booking.status !='Cancelled' and booking.email_sent == False:
                    booking.status = 'Completed'
                    booking.email_sent = True
                    booking.save()

                    # Format and Serialise Date and Time
                    formatted_date = {'date': booking.booking_date.strftime('%A %d %B %Y')}
                    json_date = formatted_date['date']
                    print(json_date)
                    

                    # Add SendGrid Template ID's
                    COMPLETED_BOOKING_TEMPLATE_ID = 'd-80e812aa2cc0456299b8fc22b6d3658a'

                    # Send confirmation email of the booking.
                           
                    booking_message = Mail(from_email='toursbookings@vis.org.au',
                        to_emails=[booking.email])

                    # Add Template ID to booking message.

                    booking_message.template_id = COMPLETED_BOOKING_TEMPLATE_ID

                    # Add Dynamic Data

                    booking_message.dynamic_template_data = {

                        'contact_name': booking.contact_name,
                        'booking_date': json_date,
                        'booking_time': booking.booking_time,
                        'program_type': booking.program_type,
                    }

                    # Send Email
                    try:
                        sg = SendGridAPIClient('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')
                        response = sg.send(booking_message)
                    except Exception as e:
                        print(e)

    bfbw_date_data = BFBWBookings.objects.all()

    for booking in bfbw_date_data:
        if booking.booking_date < date_today:
             if booking.status !='Cancelled' and booking.email_sent == False:
                    booking.status = 'Completed'
                    booking.email_sent = True
                    booking.save()

                    # Format and Serialise Date and Time
                    formatted_date = {'date': booking.booking_date.strftime('%A %d %B %Y')}
                    json_date = formatted_date['date']
                    print(json_date)
                    

                    # Add SendGrid Template ID's
                    COMPLETED_BOOKING_TEMPLATE_ID = 'd-80e812aa2cc0456299b8fc22b6d3658a'

                    # Send confirmation email of the booking.
                           
                    booking_message = Mail(from_email='toursbookings@vis.org.au',
                        to_emails=[booking.email])

                    # Add Template ID to booking message.

                    booking_message.template_id = COMPLETED_BOOKING_TEMPLATE_ID

                    # Add Dynamic Data

                    booking_message.dynamic_template_data = {

                        'contact_name': booking.contact_name,
                        'booking_date': json_date,
                        'booking_time': booking.booking_time,
                        'program_type': booking.program_type,
                    }

                    # Send Email
                    try:
                        sg = SendGridAPIClient('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')
                        response = sg.send(booking_message)
                    except Exception as e:
                        print(e)

    tour_date_data = SchoolTourBookings.objects.all()

    for booking in tour_date_data:
        if booking.booking_date < date_today:
             if booking.status !='Cancelled' and booking.email_sent == False:
                    booking.status = 'Completed'
                    booking.email_sent = True
                    booking.save()

                    # Format and Serialise Date and Time
                    formatted_date = {'date': booking.booking_date.strftime('%A %d %B %Y')}
                    json_date = formatted_date['date']
                    print(json_date)
                    

                    # Add SendGrid Template ID's
                    COMPLETED_BOOKING_TEMPLATE_ID = 'd-80e812aa2cc0456299b8fc22b6d3658a'

                    # Send confirmation email of the booking.
                           
                    booking_message = Mail(from_email='toursbookings@vis.org.au',
                        to_emails=[booking.email])

                    # Add Template ID to booking message.

                    booking_message.template_id = COMPLETED_BOOKING_TEMPLATE_ID

                    # Add Dynamic Data

                    booking_message.dynamic_template_data = {

                        'contact_name': booking.contact_name,
                        'booking_date': json_date,
                        'booking_time': booking.booking_time,
                        'program_type': booking.program_type,
                    }

                    # Send Email
                    try:
                        sg = SendGridAPIClient('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')
                        response = sg.send(booking_message)
                    except Exception as e:
                        print(e)
```

Comment: You probably should look into django's management commands as it sounds like that might suit your needs. More advanced than that would be a celery task, but for that you'd need to install celery and setup a celery broker which django can connect to.

Answer (score 1):

AppScheduler can be used to run specific functions in a view on a schedule.
https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/userguide.html

Answer (score 1):

As already suggested by @markwalker_ , I could also just suggest these 2 ways.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone


class Booking(models.Model):
    contact_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    booking_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

**1. Using [Django management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/custom-management-commands/) along with a scheduler such as [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron), [AWS EventBridge](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-create-rule-schedule.html), [AWS CloudWatch Events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-cloudwatchevents-expressions.html), etc.**

File directory structure:

```
.
├── manage.py
├── my_app
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── management
│   │   ├── commands
│   │   │   ├── completed_bookings.py
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   ├── 0002_booking.py
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
└── my_proj
    ├── asgi.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── settings.py
    ├── urls.py
    └── wsgi.py
```

completed_bookings.py

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone

from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand

from my_app.models import Booking


class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = "View completed bookings"

    def handle(self, *args, **options) -> None:
        found = Booking.objects.filter(status="Completed").values("contact_name", "status")
        print(f"{datetime.now(timezone.utc)} Found completed bookings: {found}")
```

Sample run

```
$ python3 manage.py completed_bookings
2021-08-06 06:01:07.939931+00:00 Found completed bookings: <QuerySet [{'contact_name': 'Goku', 'status': 'Completed'}, {'contact_name': 'Majin Buu', 'status': 'Completed'}]>
```

Scheduled run

Add the scheduled process to the cron list. For better visibility of the execution, we would run it once every minute and redirect the output to a log file.

```
$ crontab -e
* * * * * /home/nponcian/Documents/my_proj/venv/bin/python3 /home/nponcian/Documents/my_proj/manage.py completed_bookings >> /home/nponcian/Documents/my_proj/completed_bookings.log 2>&1
```

View the scheduled triggers to the command

```
$ tail -f /var/log/syslog | grep CRON
Aug  6 13:48:01 ubuntu20 CRON[7165]: (nponcian) CMD (/home/nponcian/Documents/my_proj/venv/bin/python3 /home/nponcian/Documents/my_proj/manage.py completed_bookings >> /home/nponcian/Documents/my_proj/completed_bookings.log 2>&1)
Aug  6 13:49:01 ubuntu20 CRON[7211]: (nponcian) CMD (/home/nponcian/Documents/my_proj/venv/bin/python3 /home/nponcian/Documents/my_proj/manage.py completed_bookings >> /home/nponcian/Documents/my_proj/completed_bookings.log 2>&1)
Aug  6 13:50:01 ubuntu20 CRON[7254]: (nponcian) CMD (/home/nponcian/Documents/my_proj/venv/bin/python3 /home/nponcian/Documents/my_proj/manage.py completed_bookings >> /home/nponcian/Documents/my_proj/completed_bookings.log 2>&1)
Aug  6 13:51:01 ubuntu20 CRON[7294]: (nponcian) CMD (/home/nponcian/Documents/my_proj/venv/bin/python3 /home/nponcian/Documents/my_proj/manage.py completed_bookings >> /home/nponcian/Documents/my_proj/completed_bookings.log 2>&1)
```

View the actual execution of the command

```
$ tail -f /home/nponcian/Documents/my_proj/completed_bookings.log
2021-08-06 05:48:02.310365+00:00 Found completed bookings: <QuerySet [{'contact_name': 'Goku', 'status': 'Completed'}, {'contact_name': 'Majin Buu', 'status': 'Completed'}]>
2021-08-06 05:49:01.741647+00:00 Found completed bookings: <QuerySet [{'contact_name': 'Goku', 'status': 'Completed'}, {'contact_name': 'Majin Buu', 'status': 'Completed'}]>
2021-08-06 05:50:02.133730+00:00 Found completed bookings: <QuerySet [{'contact_name': 'Goku', 'status': 'Completed'}, {'contact_name': 'Majin Buu', 'status': 'Completed'}]>
2021-08-06 05:51:01.565581+00:00 Found completed bookings: <QuerySet [{'contact_name': 'Goku', 'status': 'Completed'}, {'contact_name': 'Majin Buu', 'status': 'Completed'}]>
```

As you can see, the completed_bookings command was successfully invoked as a script once for every minute.

**2. Using [Celery beat](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/periodic-tasks.html) with a broker such as [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/), [Redis](https://redis.io/), etc.**

Additional requirements

- RabbitMQ, either as an app or a docker container or whatever
- Celery <python3 -m pip install celery>
- Gevent <python3 -m pip install gevent>

File directory structure:

```
.
├── manage.py
├── my_app
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   └── 0001_initial.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── my_proj
│   ├── asgi.py
│   ├── celery.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
└── task
    ├── booking.py
    └── __init__.py
```

booking.py

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone

from celery import shared_task

from my_app.models import Booking


@shared_task
def completed_bookings():
        found = Booking.objects.filter(status="Completed").values("contact_name", "status")
        print(f"{datetime.now(timezone.utc)} Found completed bookings: {found}")
```

celery.py

```
import os

from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import crontab
from kombu import Exchange, Queue

# Set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "my_proj.settings")

app = Celery("my_proj")

# For the complete list of possible settings, see https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html
app.conf.update(
    broker_url=os.getenv("CELERY_BROKER_URL", "amqp://guest:guest@127.0.0.1:5672//"),
    result_backend=os.getenv("CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND", None),
    imports=["task.booking"],
    timezone="UTC",
    # List the queues for reference of usage
    task_queues=[
        Queue(
            "my_cron",
            Exchange("my_cron", type="direct"),
            routing_key="my_cron",
        ),
    ],
    task_default_queue="my_cron",
    task_default_exchange="my_cron",
    task_default_routing_key="my_cron",
    # Setup the task routes
    task_routes={
        "task.booking.completed_bookings": {
            "routing_key": "my_cron",
            "queue": "my_cron",
        },
    },
    # Setup the cron jobs
    beat_schedule={
        "task.booking.completed_bookings": {
            "task": "task.booking.completed_bookings",
            "schedule": crontab(minute='*'),
        },
    },
)
```

Producer of the task, the one that triggers the task

```
$ celery --app=my_proj beat --loglevel=INFO
[2021-08-06 06:21:34,908: INFO/MainProcess] beat: Starting...
[2021-08-06 06:21:34,929: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task task.booking.completed_bookings (task.booking.completed_bookings)
[2021-08-06 06:22:00,000: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task task.booking.completed_bookings (task.booking.completed_bookings)
[2021-08-06 06:23:00,050: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task task.booking.completed_bookings (task.booking.completed_bookings)
[2021-08-06 06:24:00,040: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task task.booking.completed_bookings (task.booking.completed_bookings)
```

Consumer of the task, the one that accepts the task

```
$ celery --app=my_proj worker --queues=my_cron --concurrency=10 --pool=gevent --loglevel=INFO
[2021-08-06 06:21:34,936: INFO/MainProcess] Task task.booking.completed_bookings[b8165359-778e-42f8-98fe-c8cde56eca8c] received
[2021-08-06 06:21:34,945: WARNING/MainProcess] 2021-08-06 06:21:34.938737+00:00 Found completed bookings: <QuerySet [{'contact_name': 'Goku', 'status': 'Completed'}, {'contact_name': 'Majin Buu', 'status': 'Completed'}]>
[2021-08-06 06:21:34,945: WARNING/MainProcess] 

[2021-08-06 06:21:34,945: INFO/MainProcess] Task task.booking.completed_bookings[b8165359-778e-42f8-98fe-c8cde56eca8c] succeeded in 0.007730239000011352s: None
[2021-08-06 06:22:00,005: INFO/MainProcess] Task task.booking.completed_bookings[aa8204aa-8253-4fc5-bfe5-5814ba362fc9] received
[2021-08-06 06:22:00,011: WARNING/MainProcess] 2021-08-06 06:22:00.008650+00:00 Found completed bookings: <QuerySet [{'contact_name': 'Goku', 'status': 'Completed'}, {'contact_name': 'Majin Buu', 'status': 'Completed'}]>
[2021-08-06 06:22:00,011: WARNING/MainProcess] 

[2021-08-06 06:22:00,012: INFO/MainProcess] Task task.booking.completed_bookings[aa8204aa-8253-4fc5-bfe5-5814ba362fc9] succeeded in 0.004510529000071983s: None
[2021-08-06 06:23:00,054: INFO/MainProcess] Task task.booking.completed_bookings[7da463b2-4fd8-427f-b6aa-c32ea0cdfdef] received
[2021-08-06 06:23:00,062: WARNING/MainProcess] 2021-08-06 06:23:00.058649+00:00 Found completed bookings: <QuerySet [{'contact_name': 'Goku', 'status': 'Completed'}, {'contact_name': 'Majin Buu', 'status': 'Completed'}]>
[2021-08-06 06:23:00,062: WARNING/MainProcess] 

[2021-08-06 06:23:00,063: INFO/MainProcess] Task task.booking.completed_bookings[7da463b2-4fd8-427f-b6aa-c32ea0cdfdef] succeeded in 0.005619957999442704s: None
[2021-08-06 06:24:00,047: INFO/MainProcess] Task task.booking.completed_bookings[253930f2-7b36-4ef6-9369-e100499eb77d] received
[2021-08-06 06:24:00,058: WARNING/MainProcess] 2021-08-06 06:24:00.052540+00:00 Found completed bookings: <QuerySet [{'contact_name': 'Goku', 'status': 'Completed'}, {'contact_name': 'Majin Buu', 'status': 'Completed'}]>
[2021-08-06 06:24:00,058: WARNING/MainProcess] 

[2021-08-06 06:24:00,059: INFO/MainProcess] Task task.booking.completed_bookings[253930f2-7b36-4ef6-9369-e100499eb77d] succeeded in 0.00852864300031797s: None
```